# Inserting tag within a tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, insert, tags, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML structure:

```html
<BODY><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2></BODY>
```

I need to insert a table just prior to `</BODY>` using BeautifulSoup.

What I have till now is:

```
re.sub(r'\s/BODY\s', '<Table>Test<Table></BODY>', BeautifulSoup(report, "lxml"))
```

The error I get is:

```css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    execfile("C:\Users\My_PC\Desktop\Report.py")
  File "C:\Users\My_PC\Desktop\Report.py", line 10, in <module>
    re.sub(r'\s/BODY\s', '<Table>Test<Table></BODY>', BeautifulSoup(report, "lxml"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: re.sub() needs string as the last argument but u have given BeautifulSoup object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex, you can just [append](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) the table to the body:

```
In [45]: soup = BeautifulSoup("<BODY><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2></BODY>", "html.parser")

In [46]: soup.body.append(BeautifulSoup("<table>Test</table>","html.parser"))

In [47]: soup
Out[47]: <body><tag1></tag1><tag2></tag2><table>Test</table></body>
```